# $\chi^2$ Test Process Validation

Tags: statistics

```
Category  Observed  Expected  (O-E)  (O-E)^2  (O-E)^2 / E
    0         6         5       1       1          0.5
    1         6         5       1       1          0.5
    2         3         5       2       4          2
    3         3         5       2       4          2
    4         4         5       1       1          0.5
    5         5         5       0       0          0
    6         3         5       2       4          2
    7         8         5       3       9          4.5
    8         5         5       0       0          0
    9         7         5       2       4          2

 50    14 <---- ChiSquare Value
```

Can anyone confirm that I did this correctly? Basically I did it in Excel, taking $50$ random numbers between $0$ and $9$ using `= RANDBETWEEN(0,9)`.

I am interested in knowing if I did the process correctly.

Referenced: http://math.hws.edu/javamath/ryan/ChiSquare.html

Comment: You *may* also/instead want to try http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with most of your spreadsheet; however, I think the last column needs some attention. I think it should be

```
0.2
0.2
0.8
0.8
0.2
0.0
0.8
1.8
0.0
0.8
```

It looks like you might have divided by $2$ instead of dividing by the `Expected` column. Of course, this would change the sum, so $\chi^2 = 5.6$.